# Why is Vue's validation always returning false when I add some code?

Tags: vue.js

When I add some cod Vue's validation alway returns false although two inputs are the same. See code below.

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";
import md5 from "js-md5";
export default {
    name: "userRegister",
    data(){
        let validatePassword = (rule, value, callback) => {
            if (value === '') {
                callback(new Error('请输入密码'));
            } else if(this.registerForm.password !== this.registerForm.password2){
                callback(new Error('两次密码输入的不一致'));
            } else {
                callback();
            }
        };
        return {
            registerForm: {
                username: '',
                password: '',
                password2: '',
            },
            registerRules: {
                username: [
                    {required: true, message: '请输入账号', trigger: 'blur'},
                    {min: 8, max: 20, message: '账号长度需在8~20位之间', trigger: 'blur'},
                ],
                password: [
                    {min: 6, max: 20, message: '密码长度需在6~20位之间', trigger: 'blur'},
                ],
                password2: [
                    {min: 6, max: 20, message: '密码长度需在6~20位之间', trigger: 'blur'},
                    {validator: validatePassword, trigger: 'blur'}
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        handlerLogin(){
            this.$router.push("/login")
        },
        handlerRegister(){
            this.$refs["registerForm"].validate((valid) => {
                if (valid) {
                    let sendForm = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.registerForm))
  // when i add the following two line code, the valid will be false although the input is the same
                    // sendForm.password1 = md5(sendForm.password1)
                    // sendForm.password2 = md5(sendForm.password2)
                    axios.post("/register", sendForm).then((response) => {
                        if (response.data.error !== ""){
                            this.$message.error(response.data.msg)
                            return
                        }
                        this.$message.success("注册成功")
                        this.$router.push("/login")
                    })
                } else {
                    console.log(valid)
                    console.log(this.registerForm)
                    console.log("error")
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Why does it return false?

Comment: You don't have to guess what your code is doing. Use your browser developer tools. You might even want to install [vue.js dev tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd) if you're in Chrome.

Comment: Hexstring of a MD5 hash is 32 characters.